# Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch not working after installing doctormo's PPA on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Yesterday I installed doctormo's PPA package of the Wacom drivers to get a new Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch working on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS laptop, as instructed [here](http://frankgroeneveld.nl/2010/04/11/get-wacom-bamboo-fun-pen-working-in-ubuntu-lucid/) and dozens of other web pages.  Things were working fine, but today things broke.  Some symptoms:

- right-/middle-clicks don't work
- `xsetwacom list devices` shows nothing/is empty
- clicking causes the mouse pointer to stop moving - it moves again if I move the stylus out of the field and back in

Some extra info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux fl 2.6.32-31-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 18:25:51 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 056a:00d1 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsmod | fgrep wacom
wacom                  32165  0
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.  Happy to provide further info.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it was due to a missing /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-wacom.conf, which was removed in a packaging screw-up in an update from just a few days ago. After adding in the one from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562 everything worked again. Thanks go to [Favux](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTina6iQ9uaMztA%2BSMUdowJit6e3c1w%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=linuxwacom-discuss).